# CakePHP bin/cake migrations migrate command returns exit code 0 on error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, database-migration

I am calling the CakePHP (v3.8.8) migration from within the deployer tool (https://deployer.org/).
The deployer tool simply calls the shell command

> bin/cake migrations migrate

to run the migrations.

If one of the migrations produce an error, the migration process is correctly cancelled.
But the CakePHP migrate command doesn't return a non-zero exit code in this situation.
Thus, the calling process is not informed about the error.

In my case, this leads to having a new software version deployed that uses an old database schema version.

I believe, the CakePHP migrate command should return the exit code returned by the Phinx migration, which is called under the hood. If I use the Phinx migrate command directly to migrate the database schema using the very same migrations scripts, the Phinx command returns the exit code 1 if an error occurs.

Is CakePHP's behavior desired?

Comment: That sounds like a possible bug that you should report over at **https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues**

Comment: @ndm Thanks! I did. https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/426